# How to read a text file into a Perl hash using the first two columns as the key

Tags: perl, file, hash

I am trying to read a file containing this into a Perl hash.

I want the first two columns to be the key and the remaining columns to be the values.

```
Celena Standard  F 01/24/94 Cancer 
Jeniffer Orlowski  F 06/24/86 None
Brent Koehler  M 12/05/97  HIV
Mao Schleich  M 04/17/60  Cancer
Goldie Moultrie  F 04/05/96  None
```

This is where I got stuck.

```perl
open FILE1, "Patient_Info.txt" or die;
my %hash;

while ( my $line = <FILE1> ) {
    chomp $line;    # remove newline
    my ( $key, $value ) = split ' ', $line, 2;
    $hash{$key} = $value;
}

my @sorted_keys = sort keys %hash;
my $new         = 'Celena';

for my $new ( @sorted_keys ) {
    print "$new $hash{$new} \n";
}
```

Comment: Your main problem is that you've specified a limit of 2 in your `split`, which will give you at most 2 fields: the first name, and then everything else.

Answer (score 1):

The first two fields are joined on `''`, and the remaining fields are left as an array reference:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %data;

while (<DATA>) {
    my @fields = split;
    my $key = join('', splice(@fields, 0, 2));
    $data{$key} = \@fields;
}

for my $key (sort(keys(%data))) {
    printf("%s: %s\n", $key, join(' ', @{$data{$key}}));
}

__DATA__
Celena Standard F 01/24/94 Cancer
Jeniffer Orlowski F 06/24/86 None
Brent Koehler M 12/05/97 HIV
Mao Schleich M 04/17/60 Cancer
Goldie Moultrie F 04/05/96 None
```

Output:

```
BrentKoehler: M 12/05/97 HIV
CelenaStandard: F 01/24/94 Cancer
GoldieMoultrie: F 04/05/96 None
JenifferOrlowski: F 06/24/86 None
MaoSchleich: M 04/17/60 Cancer
```

Comment: Please can you guide me on how to print the hash without the data dump, using a print statement for example. I am still learning perl. Thanks

Comment: @WisdomHambolu Edited answer to show a loop over the keys of `%data`.

Comment: This was basically the logic i was missing "The first two fields are joined on  ' ', and the remaining fields are left as an array reference" . Thanks @MattJacob this was really helpful.

Comment: @WisdomHambolu That, and you were only getting the first field, not the first two fields.

Comment: true, forgot to mention that.

Comment: @MattJacob: While it satisfies the requirement, simply concatenating the first two fields makes it impossible to separate them again

Answer (score 1):

Some notes on your code

You should

- ***Always*** `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of *every* Perl program that you write
- Use *lexical* file handles, like `my $file1` rather than `FILE1`, as they are much safer and more useful than global ones
- Please choose better variable identifiers. In `%hash`, the `%` says that it's a hash so you may as well have used `%_`. Is this a personnel list perhaps? Or a subscriber list?

I can't work out what you're hoping for with `my $new = 'Celina'` as you never use that variable again

You don't say *how* you want the data stored in the hash, so I've use an array to store the last three fields

I've added the `Data::Dump` output so that you can see the structure of the resulting hash, as well as a simple `while` loop that reproduces the original data (in a different order)

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use autodie;

my %data = do {

    open my $fh, '<', 'patient_info.txt';

    map {
        my ($first, $second, @info) = split;
        "$first $second" => \@info;
    } <$fh>;
};

use Data::Dump;
dd \%data;

print "\n";

while ( my ($name, $info) = each %data ) {
    print "$name @$info\n";
}
```

#### output

```
{
  "Brent Koehler"     => ["M", "12/05/97", "HIV"],
  "Celena Standard"   => ["F", "01/24/94", "Cancer"],
  "Goldie Moultrie"   => ["F", "04/05/96", "None"],
  "Jeniffer Orlowski" => ["F", "06/24/86", "None"],
  "Mao Schleich"      => ["M", "04/17/60", "Cancer"],
}

Celena Standard F 01/24/94 Cancer
Mao Schleich M 04/17/60 Cancer
Jeniffer Orlowski F 06/24/86 None
Goldie Moultrie F 04/05/96 None
Brent Koehler M 12/05/97 HIV
```

Comment: I actually use strict and warnings, just forgot to post it along with the code.  I used the variable $new in debugging, it is in the final print statement. It is a patient information list by the way.   Thanks for the great tips!

Comment: @WisdomHambolu: Then `my %hash` should be something like `my %patients`. And please don't leave rubbish from your debugging in the code that you publish: it takes time to process, decide to discard it, and say so in the answer. We don't know whether it's a relic from debugging! Take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Just creating an MCVE may well expose the bug to you, and it's not fair to expect people who are offering to help you for free to deal with junk code.